# Social share in angular Universal not working if i am navigating to lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, socialshare

I have implemented server side rendering in angular 6 and it is working but in social share scenario i am facing some problems. Problems are listed below.

1- I am using short url for sharing. So I have created a lazy module which reads the short url and than navigate to another lazy loaded module on the basis of type of url.

suppose types are car,bike,truck.
On these route i have handelling of these Type and the view regarding its type.

Demo code-

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            this.getAllSharedContent(res.id);
        })

    }
getAllSharedContent(id) {
 this.sharedUrlService.getContentFromSharedUrlId(id).subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res);
       this.router.navigate(['/transport/' + new LowerCasePipe().transform(res.type) + '/' + new ReplaceWhiteSpace().transform(res.title) + '/' + new ReplaceCpIds().transform(res.id, '')], { queryParams: { page: 0 } });
 })
}
```

**I want the rendered page where i have navigated. but it is returning the index.html page.**

Comment: new LowerCasePipe().transform(res.type) = ret.type.toLowerCase() ?? :)

Comment: this is used for making the dynamic url and it is working fine.I am navigating to that page.